# htaccess rewrite URL to subdirectory php

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I would like to rewrite all URLs, which starts with a */lp/* to a php file in a subdirectory.

This is my current htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^$ /lp/ [L,R=301]

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

This is the behaviour I wish to realize:

```
example .org/lp/      => example.org/lp/ (because index.php is there)
example .org/lp/test  => example.org/lp/index.php?p=test
example .org/lp/foo   => example.org/lp/index.php?p=foo
```

I've tried this rule and many others, but it doesn't work:

```
RewriteRule ^/lp/([^/\.]+)/?$ /lp/index.php?p=$1 [L]
```

Maybe someone has an idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: RewriteRule in htaccess get path without forward slash, so `^/lp` never matches

Comment: @Deadooshka wow, great, it works! I've removed the slash at the start. Thank you!!